# How to run certain part of CSS3 animation in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to run a certain part of a CSS3 animation in reverse order after it runs forwards.

The part I am trying to get is the keyframes from 50% to 100% to go in reverse after they have gone forwards.

I have 5 animations that go in the order fallA, fallB, fallC, fallD, and fallE then after fallE is done, I need it to go fallE, fallD, fallC, fallB, and fallA; but, only to the 50% keyframe from the 100% it is at.

Is there a way I can do this with CSS or even javascript / jquery?

Here is the animation code:

```
    .animated.fallA{
        -moz-animation: fallA 1s forwards ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: fallA 1s forwards ease-in-out;
        animation: fallA 1s forwards ease-in-out;
    }
    .animated.fallB{
        -moz-animation: fallB 1.2s forwards ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: fallB 1.2s forwards ease-in-out;
        animation: fallB 1.2s forwards ease-in-out;
    }
    .animated.fallC{
        -moz-animation: fallC 1.4s forwards ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: fallC 1.4s forwards ease-in-out;
        animation: fallC 1.4s fowards ease-in-out;
    }
    .animated.fallD{
        -moz-animation: fallD 1.6s forwards ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: fallD 1.6s forwards ease-in-out;
        animation: fallD 1.6s forwards ease-in-out;
    }
    .animated.fallE{
        -moz-animation: fallE 1.8s forwards ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: fallE 1.8s forwards ease-in-out;
        animation: fallE 1.8s forwards ease-in-out;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes fallA{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:0;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fallA{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:0;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fallA{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:0;
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes fallB{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-20px;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fallB{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-20px;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fallB{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-20px;
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes fallC{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-30px;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fallC{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-30px;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fallC{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-30px;
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes fallD{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-20px;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fallD{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-20px;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fallD{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:-20px;
        }       
    }
    @-moz-keyframes fallE{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:0;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fallE{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:0;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fallE{
        0%{
            position:relative;
            opacity:0.0;
            top:-100px;
        }
        50%{
            opacity:1.0;
            top:0;
        }
        100%{
            top:0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write another keyframe animation in reverse (or using direction reverse) that has your needed animation from 0% to 100% and runs in half the time.  So when the animation ends you could use jQuery to bind to the animation end and add a class that would apply the 'reverse' animation.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried with this?

```
.foo{
animation-direction:alternate;
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
}
```

[here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-direction) is the mozilla dev network reference
and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-direction-property) the W3C reference

Comment: Correct answer, but wrong link unfortunately. [w3schools is not related to the W3C!](http://w3fools.com/) Better link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-direction (change it and get an upvote :-)

Comment: Yes, I was just about to say that. That is the W3Schools link. Check out the website W3Fools. But anyway, thank you. I will look into it.

Comment: I see how I can use alternate now, but how can I apply it so that it runs backwards for only half of the animation ( from 100% to 50%) and then not run forwards again.

Comment: OP wants to return to the 50% keyframe.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the proper link. I see how I can use alternate now, but how can I apply it so that it runs backwards for only half of the animation ( from 100% to 50%) and then not run forwards again.

Comment: I agree with Bergi, although I'm not sure if dev.mozilla _is_ related to the W3C. Better link to the real W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-direction-property @IrfanM

Comment: @IrfanM looking at your fallA animation (which last 1s), and looking at the W3C specs i guess you can write `animation-direction:alternate,0.5;` but i.m not sure about it. can you provide some html or a working fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at cubic-bezier as an easing function, in stead of the ease-in-out.
http://cubic-bezier.com

You would have to make your animation go to your current 50% mark, and by using the correct bezier, you make make it 'overshoot' and move back. Something like this: http://cubic-bezier.com/#.29,.61,.79,3

**edit:**
I did not look at your animation code carefull enough it seems. Bezier is not what you are after, as you are trying to create a bounce effect, and not an elastic 'overshoot' effect (if I understand your code correctly) http://jsfiddle.net/4KwY8/1/

The solution is not that hard. You just need to define your keyframes a bit diiferently for your fallB, C and D. The css would look something like this:

```
@keyframes fallB{
    0%{
        position:relative;
        opacity:0.0;
        top:-100px;
    }
    33%, 100%{
        opacity:1.0;
        top:0;
    }
    66%{
        top:-20px;
    }
}
```

As you can see I use the middle keyframe both for the 1/3 point and the 3/3 point. The fiddle with this change included looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4KwY8/2/

I think this is what you where after. You might have to do some finetuning in terms of timing and keyframe positioning, but I think you get the general idea. If it is not clear, feel free to ask.

PS: For inspiration, some more cool css animation effects can be found here: http://daneden.me/animate/

Comment: I'm confused on how I can use cubic-bezier to reverse the animation up to a certain point. It seems it is just a replacement for ease-in-out.

Comment: try putting up a fiddle with the code you have now, and I will do my best to demonstrate

Comment: You make the target of your animation the half way point and use the bezier easing to overshoot by 50% and then finish up in the middle. It's a hack surely?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to hand code your animation, and working round all the limitations of CSS 3 transitions, I'd recommend you do yourself a big favour and use one of the various JavaScript tween libraries such as the [Greensock animation platform](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) (GSAP).

It's incredibly powerful, with support for delays, staggers, repeats, loops, reverse etc. You could probably rewrite the above (plus the additional functionality you need) in a few lines with GSAP.

You can see how it stacks up against CSS 3 transitions [here](http://www.greensock.com/transitions/).